# WP Multisite: Do a function after blog is activated

Tags: multisite

I wanted to add an action on when a user activated the blog through standard signup process, all my custom meta on the registration will be inserted on my modified `wp_blogs` table.

Here is my code for the custom signup meta.

```
add_filter( 'add_signup_meta', 'custom_add_signup_meta' );

function custom_add_signup_meta ( $blogmeta = array() ) {

        $the_country = $_POST['country-origin'];
        $d_currency = $_POST['user_currency'];
        $d_zone = $_POST['state-origin'];

        $blogmeta['countries_id'] = $the_country;
        $blogmeta['default_currency'] = $d_currency;
        $blogmeta['zone_id'] = $d_zone;

    return $blogmeta;

}
```

Now I want to hook the function below somewhere applicable which has arguments of `$blog_id` and my custom meta `$blogmeta`

```
function insert_custom_datas1($blog_id, $blogmeta) {
        global $wpdb;
        $wp_blogs = $wpdb->base_prefix . "blogs";

        $wpdb->query("UPDATE `" . $wp_blogs . "` SET `countries_id`='".$wpdb->escape($blogmeta['countries_id'])."', `default_currency`='".$wpdb->escape($blogmeta['default_currency'])."', `zone_id`='".$wpdb->escape($blogmeta['zone_id'])."' where `blog_id` = '" . (int)$blog_id . "'");

}
```

Please help in accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
add_action('wpmu_new_blog', 'insert_custom_datas1', 10, 6);
function insert_custom_datas1($blog_id, $user_id, $domain, $path, $site_id, $blogmeta) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Let us know how it goes?